# Checkbox doesn't get clicked after adding it to bottom of an anchor container

Tags: javascript, css, html, checkbox

I am trying to add a new checkbox to a search result page of a travel website with result cards defined as an anchor tag inside a div. Something like below:

```
<div class="cards">
    <a href="some link">Some Information</a>
    <div id="price"> Price</div>
    .....
</div>
```

Now, this anchor tag link is over entire `cards` div. I am trying to add a checkbox within this `card` div to the bottom right but somehow when I try to tick the checkbox, the `Some Information` link gets clicks as it is overlaid to entire card.

Below is the code for my checkbox:

```
<div id="myContainer">
  <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" id="myCheckbox" value="red">
  <label for="myCheckbox_01_item" class="text">Add to Compare</label>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
  @CHARSET "UTF-8";

/* Main Classes */
.text{
    position: relative;
    /* margin-top: .70588235rem; */
    color: #3e3e3e;
    margin: 13px 11px;
    float: right;
}
#myCheckbox{
    transform: scale(2);
/*  margin: 10px; */
}

#myContainer {
    outline: black dashed 1px;
    width: 238px;
   background-color: #ffcb00;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: auto;
}


#myContainer input[type="checkbox"][name="myCheckbox"]:not(:checked) {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 25px;
    border: black solid 1px;
    background: #FFF ;
    margin: 12px 13px;
    float: left;
}

#myContainer input[type="checkbox"][name="myCheckbox"]:checked  {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 25px;
    border: black solid 1px;
    background: #00355f;
    margin: 12px 13px;
    float: left;
}

#myContainer input[type="checkbox"][name="myCheckbox"] + label + label.text {
    line-height: 18px;
    font: normal 12px arial;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 27px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}
```

Also, if I am keeping it in the bottom left, it appears below the card div box and works fine. PFA the two images to give you the idea about the UI.

[image: Left_Checkbox]

Right Checkbox:

[image: Right_checkbox]

Comment: The code in your question doesn't replicate the issue - the checkbox works fine. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see the problem.

Comment: The checkbox code works fine. It's just that when the checkbox container div is moved to right and when I try to tick, it clicks the anchor tag and opens the link associated in new tab. How can I separate it and keep it to bottom right?

Comment: You need to show us the code that causes it so that we can replicate the issue.

Comment: Try `z-index` it's a layer problem.

Comment: @Mouser:Perfect. This is what the solution is.

Comment: Great, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the checkbox placed inside the anchor tag. You should first remove the href value of anchor tag for that (whenever mouseover the checkbox element). I have created a sample snippet using jquery for this. Please take a look.

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/demaxglobal/nb7k1fy4/)**

Jquery event to change the href value of anchor tag while mouseover on checkbox

```
 $( ".checkbox-container" ).mouseover(function(){
 $("a").attr("href", "")
 });
```

Sample HTML

```
<a href="#">
<div class="checkbox-container">
<input type="checkbox" value="some value">Some Value
</div>

</a>
```

Hope this helps